# Java - Query Spring com data atual

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa

Tenho o seguinte repositório com o seguinte método

```
@Query("SELECT m FROM Money m WHERE m.data = CURRENT_DATE()")
Money findTop1IfHasMoneyInCurrentDate();
```

A minha classe money está assim:

```
 @Entity
@Table(name="MONEY_DATA", schema="DEMO_PIMS")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(allowGetters=true)
public class Money  {

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID_REG")
    private Long Id;

    @Column(name="DATA")
    @JsonFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date data;

    @Column(name="DOLAR")
    private Double dolar;

    @Column(name="EURO")
    private Double euro;

    @Column(name="LIBRA")
    private Double libra;

    public Money() {

    }
```

Mas está sempre retornando null quando chamo o "findTop1IfHasMoneyInCurrentDate()" sendo que tem registros no dia atual.

O que fazer na Query para pegar um registro de acordo com o dia atual?

Comment: A função que chama o repositório que executa a query, já tentou ver como ela retorna? Pelo que vi, a query retornaria um objeto `Money`. Já fez algum `System.out.println` com o resultado da consulta? Já pegou o corpo da requisição recebida como String para verificar se está tudo em ordem?

Comment: `CURRENT_DATE()` - `java.sql.Date` - retorna a data apenas, seu campo está mapeado como `TIMESTAMP` - `java.sql.Timestamp`. Use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` - provavelmente não resolverá, já que tu quer do dia e não do exato _date time_ - ou altere sua query. A sua query também não limita, então pode dar erro também, desse jeito aí retorna uma coleção.

Comment: Qual o SQL gerado quando esta consulta é executada?

Comment: Conseguiu chegar na solução? A resposta abaixo te ajudou?

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com a especificação do Java Persistence API, existem funções predefinidas CURRENT_DATE, CURRENT_TIME and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

O detalhe é no uso dela, que **não leva os parênteses**, comuns para funções em linguagens de programação. Veja:

```
@Query("SELECT m FROM Money m WHERE m.data = CURRENT_DATE")
Money findTop1IfHasMoneyInCurrentDate();
```